# Password with lookbehind assertions

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

Hi I am getting started with regex and I am already facing a problem with finding solutionto write a code that accepts password using lookbehind Assertion...

```
`import re
   e = re.compile(r"[A-Za-z\d]((?<=[A-Z]).*)((?<=[a-z]).*)((?<=\d).*)")

while(True):
  while(True):
    password= input("Enter Password: ")
    print(password)
    result = e.search(password)
    print(result)

    if result is not None:
        print("Correct")
        break
    print("False")`
```

It accept any input if I enter A password that starts with an Uppercase caracter followed by lowercase caracter and one digit. However, it refuses Any password that starts with a digit.
My question: is there an order pattern that i should follow while using lookbehind assertions ?

Comment: Please add some examples for passwords that work and those who do not work, but are supposed to work

Comment: The pattern is usually evaluated from left to right. In this case if you enter a character in this range `[A-Za-z\d]` the next part of the pattern will immediately assert a char A-Z to the left `(?<=[A-Z])` that is why it can not start with a digit. There is a match if all assertions are true, and you specified the order of appearance in the pattern.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what you want to achieve. For example, the password `0Axxbyy3zz` is seen as correct, even though you mentioned that passwords with a digit at the start are refused.

Comment: @ErikWessel Example of accepted Passwords: Hello1, hElLo1

Comment: @ErikWessel Examples of unaccepted Passwords: 1Hello,1hEllo

Comment: Would it be okay to not use lookbehind for the regex? Do you just want to match any occurances of alphanumeric characters?

Comment: On a production web server, this regex would be a __serious__ DOS attack vector. Just enter a very long string `AaAaAaAa...Aa` and you'll consume most of the server's CPU time.

Comment: Perhaps you want a pattern without lookarounds like `^[A-Za-z]*[A-Z][A-Za-z]*\d[A-Za-z\d]*$` https://regex101.com/r/vL6hKU/1 Or match a lowercase char after an uppercase char `^[A-Za-z]*[A-Z]+[a-z][A-Za-z]*\d[A-Za-z\d]*$`

Comment: @MohamedChiha What password policy are you trying to enforce? And what makes you think you need lookbehind for that?

Comment: @RuudHelderman It's just a homework.. it demands using lookbehind for passwords

Comment: Again, what is the password policy? From your own attempt, I gather there must be at least one uppercase letter, at least one lowercase letter, and at least one digit. Are non-alphanumerical characters allowed? Are non-ASCII characters allowed? Is there a minimal password length? A maximum password length?

Comment: @RuudHelderman at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter and one digit and a minimum length of 6 caracters

Comment: Sounds like a cruel joke from your teacher. This is no use case for lookbehind!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match passwords like `1Hello` and `1hEllo` like you described, you could go for just

```
e = re.compile(r"\w+")
```

for passwords with at least one character or with

```
e = re.compile(r"\w{8}\w*")
```

for passwords of `length >= 8`

`\w` stands for any alphanumeric character ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html))

Answer (score 0):

I would find it strange for any teacher to demand lookbehind in this case.

The most obvious approach is **lookahead**:

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d).{6,}
```

You can even do it without lookaround, but then you'd better make it a negative test (i.e. a regex matching the *invalid* passwords rather than the valid ones).

```
^(.{,5}|[^A-Z]*|[^a-z]*|\D*)$
```

So what about lookbehind? I could try and reverse my initial attempt:

```
.{6,}(?<=[A-Z].*)(?<=[a-z].*)(?<=\d.*)$
```

This works in JavaScript, but not in Python:
Python's regex engine demands *fixed-width* lookbehind.

Oh sure, I could introduce a lookbehind. There you go.

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d).{6,}(?<=...)
```

But it serves no purpose.
I'm just adding lookbehind for the sake of having lookbehind in my regex;
not because it brings any benefit.

I've always considered lookbehind to be my last resort, in case everything else fails or results in a ridiculously big regex.
Here, that is definitely not the case.